# Postman - How to add items into array and then using array elements randomly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, postman

I have this json

[image]

This JSON represents a shopping cart
I need to get all "id" parameters into an array and set that array as environment variable. There can be multiple "id" parameters in JSON. Then I need to use elements from created array randomly. (I need to remove items from cart randomly based on id)

Is there a way to achieve that? I'm struggling to find a solution for that. 
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

First get the whole reponse, parse it. You have put that code in `Tests` tab of `postman`

[image]

For your case:

```
var array = JSON.parse(responseBody).order.commerceItems;

var ids = [];

for(var i=0; i< array.length; i++)
{
    ids.push(array[i].id);
}
```

Now put the `ids` in environment variable or global variable of `PostMan`.

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ProductIds",JSON.stringify(ids));
```

After this, it will look like this.
[image]

Now when you want to access a id from that ids randomly, you have to write in `Pre-request Script` tab, like this:

[image]
and in request body:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
let order = {
    commerceItems:[
        {
            name: 'test1',
            id: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'test2',
            id: 2
        },
        {
            name: 'test3',
            id: 3
        }
    ]
};

let arr = [];

for (item of order.commerceItems) {
    arr.push(item.id);
}
console.log(arr);
```

> [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to return random data from your array of object, you can doing like this :

```js
let order = {
    id: "7824t70ujhfiu",
    totalCommerce: 5,
    commerceItems:[
        {
            value: 'value 1',
            anotheValue: 'another one 1',
            name: 'name 1',
            id: "iuhvue0743bg3y"
        },
        {
            value: 'value 2',
            anotheValue: 'another one 2',
            name: 'name 2',
            id: "sdhvuhsdupvhh9y470y3yg"
        },
        {
            value: 'value 3',
            anotheValue: 'another one 3',
            name: 'name 3',
            id: "o0402t207t782yt78"
        },
        {
            value: 'value 4',
            anotheValue: 'another one 4',
            name: 'name 4',
            id: "72b07t347y74y7by"
        },
        {
            value: 'value 5',
            anotheValue: 'another one 5',
            name: 'name 5',
            id: "oin98y49yb2y49y"
        }
    ]
};

pickRandom = () => {
    var arr = order.commerceItems;
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() *arr.length)];
}

const random_data = [pickRandom(), pickRandom()];

const filter_array = [...new Map(random_data.map(item => [item.id, item])).values()];

order = {
    ...order,
    totalCommerce: filter_array.length,
    commerceItems: filter_array 
  };

console.log(order);
```